# PayPal REST completePurchase fee information

Tags: paypal

How can I get the fees from PayPal?

When I complete the purchase I can do $data = $response->getData(), and I get this information:

```
Array (
    [id] => PAYID-LYUDPFA8E292123AP955374L
    [intent] => sale
    [state] => approved
    [cart] => 3CN05415NR550735F
    [payer] => Array (
    [payment_method] => paypal
    [status] => VERIFIED
    [payer_info] => Array (
    [email] => accounting-buyer@mobipium.com
    [first_name] => test
    [last_name] => buyer
    [payer_id] => GTHZDZWYCELWU
    [shipping_address] => Array (
    [recipient_name] => test buyer
    [line1] => 1 Main St
    [city] => San Jose
    [state] => CA
    [postal_code] => 95131
    [country_code] => US
    )
    [country_code] => US
    )
    )
    [transactions] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [amount] => Array (
    [total] => 1500.00
    [currency] => EUR
    [details] => Array (
    [subtotal] => 1500.00
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [insurance] => 0.00
    [handling_fee] => 0.00
    [shipping_discount] => 0.00
    )
    )
    [payee] => Array (
    [merchant_id] => PCQDHVBJUD4WN
    [email] => accounting-facilitator@mobipium.com
    )
    [description] => 5e2837933fdc3
    [invoice_number] => 5e2837933fdc3
    [item_list] => Array (
    [shipping_address] => Array (
    [recipient_name] => test buyer
    [line1] => 1 Main St
    [city] => San Jose
    [state] => CA
    [postal_code] => 95131
    [country_code] => US
    )
    )
    [related_resources] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [sale] => Array (
    [id] => 9XL29023PP3022045
    [state] => pending
    [amount] => Array (
    [total] => 1500.00
    [currency] => EUR
    [details] => Array (
    [subtotal] => 1500.00
    [shipping] => 0.00
    [insurance] => 0.00
    [handling_fee] => 0.00
    [shipping_discount] => 0.00
    )
    )
    [payment_mode] => INSTANT_TRANSFER
    [reason_code] => RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION
    [protection_eligibility] => ELIGIBLE
    [protection_eligibility_type] => ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE
    [receivable_amount] => Array (
    [value] => 1500.00
    [currency] => EUR
    )
    [exchange_rate] => 0.8627555079
    [parent_payment] => PAYID-LYUDPFA8E292123AP955374L
    [create_time] => 2020-01-22T11:53:12Z
    [update_time] => 2020-01-22T11:53:12Z
    [links] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9XL29023PP3022045
    [rel] => self
    [method] => GET
    )
    [1] => Array (
    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9XL29023PP3022045/refund
    [rel] => refund
    [method] => POST
    )
    [2] => Array (
    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LYUDPFA8E292123AP955374L
    [rel] => parent_payment
    [method] => GET
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )
    )
    [create_time] => 2020-01-22T11:52:52Z
    [update_time] => 2020-01-22T11:53:12Z
    [links] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LYUDPFA8E292123AP955374L
    [rel] => self
    [method] => GET
    )
    )
)
```

I only can see the handling_fee field but when i access my facilitator account
https://gyazo.com/fc55e97066ee755efee7867a3c42e913
I can see the estimated field, how can i get this field?
I already do a integration with paypal and I can get that field from
`$response['data']['transactions'][0]['related_resources'][0]['sale']['transaction_fee']['value'];`
But this field sale doesn't have the `transaction_fee` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payments in `state=>approved` must be executed in order to be in `state=> completed`.

Once a payment is *completed* or at least *pending*, its sale object , available at https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/9XL29023PP3022045 in your example , should have details on financials.  This is the identifier that has actual accounting value, and which will be persisted for years in the paypal.com account.

The payment object, id PAYID-LYUDPFA8E292123AP955374L in your example, is only used during the payment approval and execution process.  It only needs to be kept around ~1 month for debug purposes, as it has no accounting value and will not be referenceable in paypal.com